# How to parse and object that have inside an array of numbers using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm working on a Spring MVC project using angularjs, I'm passing from the view the following JSON array `{name:"theName", code:"theCode",  comment:"theComment", listOfIds:["3", "4"]}`

This is my controller that receives the JSON

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createPerson/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createSep(@RequestBody final String DTOJsonObject,
        UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> dataDTOParsed ;
        dataDTOParsed = mapper.readValue(DTOJsonObject, HashMap.class);


    //I tried this but it says that a String can not be converted to ArrayList<String> 
                ArrayList<String> listIDS = new ArrayList<String>();
                listIDS = (ArrayList<String>) dataDTOParsed .get("listOfIds");
}
```

I tried using the following cast but it says that `String can not be converted to ArrayList<String>`

```
ArrayList<String> listIDS = new ArrayList<String>();
                    listIDS = (ArrayList<String>) dataDTOParsed .get(this);
```

I know how to get the other values is this value `listOfIds:["3", "4"]` that is giving me problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your JSON object has properties with different data types (String, Array...) it would be better to map it to a `Map<String, Object>` and then cast accordingly.

Code sample:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createPerson/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createSep(@RequestBody final String DTOJsonObject,
    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> parsedData;

    parsedData = mapper.readValue(DTOJsonObject, HashMap.class);

    List<String> listIDS = (ArrayList<String>)parsedData.get("listOfIds");

    for(String n : listIDS){
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```